# Session ID regeneration not working for concurrent requests

Tags: php, ajax, session, codeigniter-3

I had posted this question to the CI forum but without any answer so I am trying it here.

I am using CI for a REST API serving JSON calls from a single page app.
With CI 2.x I had a problem with session ID regeneration in a case of "chain" of requests in a short time while some of them changed session ID. I hoped that CI 3 with its brand new session library will fix it.

I upgraded to 3.0, read carefully session docs and did some tests. From my point of view the problem which occured in CI 2.x is still persisting in 3.0.

Let me explain it on an example of http requests (actually observed from a real app):

Session ID is not changing:

```
GET ... Request cookies: ci_session=123,
        Response cookies:
GET ... Request cookies: ci_session=123,
        Response cookies:
...
```

Session ID is to be regenerated:

```
GET ... Request cookies: ci_session=123, 
        Response cookies: ci_session: <deleted>, ci_session: 456
```

This request had started sooner than the previous one returned, so it is carrying the old session ID:

```
GET ... Request cookies: ci_session=123,
        Response cookies:
```

But the session ID 123 is not valid anymore so the request is regarded not authenticated.

It seems, that the locking, which was added to the new session library does not prevent this.

My session config is:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = <some path>
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 60;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

I am using session_write_close() after initial request authentication.

Is there a way how to use CI 3 for this king of requests? Am I doing something wrong?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all - if you're using sessions, it's not a RESTful API, because the whole point of using a session is to maintain state, while a REST service must be stateless.

That being said, the `sess_regenerate_destroy` setting was created exactly for a use case like yours. Set it to boolean FALSE and the old session ID will be deleted later by the garbage collector instead of immediately upon regeneration. That leaves a time window during which both the old and the new session IDs are usable, and the queued request won't be rejected.

Comment: Thank you Narf. I was hoping my question would find you and it did. The `sess_regenerate_destroy` was probably the only setting of the session library I did not understand very much. I tested your suggestion and it seems to be working. I was wondering what is the length of the time window when both the old and the new session IDs are usable. Is it the same value as `sess_expiration` (session.php line 303)?. Does it mean that all session files which are not deleted by the GC contain still usable sess ID? In my case it would be a few days old files/IDs. I am a little confused here. Thank you!

Comment: Uauu, what a speed :) I want to use long sessions (nice user experience) and frequent session ID regeneration (session fixation attack prevention). However when I use `sess_regenerate_destroy=FALSE` and a user will log out only one session will be destroyed but many opened sessions will be left waiting for GC a few hours maybe more. That’s not safe.
That leaves me with two choices:
1. Short `session_expiration` and no session ID regeneration (less user friendly but more safe),
2. Some kind of other authorization (e.g. OAuth2)
Thank you anyway for your response and your work for the CI !